# sonarqube incremental analysis is not working for team configuration

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube-4.5

I've configured sonarqube server on my local machine to run and I committed the initial project with Analysis mode.  Also, I created an ant target for the developers to run in incremental mode to view their new issues. I installed issuesReport on sonar server and using it from the ant file to generate html files.

However, when each developer syncs with svn and runs the ant target, they see violations by other developers under the new issues instead of only their issues.

I expected the sonarqube plugin only scan newly edited file by the developer, but is instead showing all the new files that are introduced by other developers.

To make it work properly I have to run an analysis mode from my machine. However this fixes the problem only for me, my colleagues still see all the violations as new.

How does SonarQube decide if an issue is new or not? If each developer has to run a full analysis every time, this would be big over head. Is there something am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

An issue is considered "new" if it does not exist on the analysis server. If you run a full analysis on a CI server on a scheduled basis, it will feed the server with issues and reduce the risk of developers seeing other developer's issues in issues report in preview mode.

Answer (score 2):

Please note, that the sonar documentation says, incremental mode is only for the developers and that too for the code they run against sonar prior to scm (SVN or GIT) commit.

See incremental section on the page: http://www.sonarqube.org/analysis-vs-preview-vs-incremental-preview-in-sonarqube/

The sonar report, when run with incremental mode, will show the developer, how much issue will be generated, if he commits the code. This way developer gets to know, what he can do to keep the sonar issues low. This is the whole purpose of incremental mode.

Hope this answers your question!!!